# How to set the example XML with WCF Auto Help?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

WCF 4 comes with auto-generated help, however we are using our own serialization schema for our service requests. How can set my own example xml/json request for users to see when they hit the help page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should this blog entry contain an answer to your question?

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/WCF-Custom-Help-Page-6f5a90f0